# HTML - Can't fit content into box after adding FORM

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to figure this out after hours of trying to diagnose it.

I have a rounded box that holds some login content.  After i add the finishing piece  it seems to jump out of the content

here's the jsfiddle of it, i am really confused

http://jsfiddle.net/Ck6Bp/

```
<p id="loginContainer">
<form>
<input type="text" name="username" value="username" />
<br/>
<input type="password" name="password" value="NSxPussinskiboots" />
<br/>   <span id="mini"><a href="#">Register</a> | <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></span> 
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Log Me In" />Login below:
<br/>
<br/>
</form>
```

```
p#loginContainer {
display:block;
font-size:1.5em;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);
padding:40px;
border-radius:6px;} 
form { width: auto; height:auto; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `<p>` tag to a `<div>` tag. I've also removed the `p` before the `#loginContainer` in the CSS file so that the id is called properly.

**HTML**

```
<div id="loginContainer">
    <form>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="username" />
    <br/>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="NSxPussinskiboots" />
    <br/>   <span id="mini"><a href="#">Register</a> | <a href="#">Forgot your password?      </a></span> 
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log Me In" />Login below:
    <br/>
    <br/>
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#loginContainer {
    display:block;
    //margin-left:60%;
    font-size:1.5em;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);
    padding:40px;
    border-radius:6px;
    text-align: left;
}
form { width: auto; height:auto; }
```

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SfMZH/.

Hope this helps!